# Opening JPG/TIFF in Preview, Can't Save from Preview

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, jpeg

User is trying to open any image file- tiff, jpg etc in the default macOS Preview app and then save/export it to a jpg- usually to the desktop or documents and cannot. See below.

System 1 Specs:
macOS 10.13.6
27-inch, Mid 2010 iMac
Core i7/8GB RAM
Outlook 16.43/20110804

System 2 Specs:
macOS 10.15.7
Macbook Pro 15-Inch, Retina, Mid 2015
Core i7/16GB RAM
Outlook 16.54 (21101001)

Steps to reproduce-

Open Outlook, double click jpg from an email, jpg opens in macOS's Preview app. Click File, Save (or Export), Desktop, receive error: "The document xyz.jpg could not be saved as xyz. you don't have permission"
Original user is not local admin. Tried with admin permissions, same result.

OR

Open any TIFF and save/export as JPG, same issue.

Have tried:
Logged on as admin, setup new profile with Outlook, using original user's outlook credentials, same result.
Cannot upgrade macOS or Office Suite. These versions are locked for compatibility. I cannot reproduce this on other Macs.
Can save JPG2000 fine, but this is incompatible with our systems.
Can export to pdf, but again, not compatible.

Users having the issue are NOT AD/Domain users, they are local to the Mac.

RELOADED System 2 from scratch. NO DATA was migrated. Issue Persists.

Comment: Where are they trying to save to? I'd imagine the default location would be somewhere deep in the bowels of Outlook's internal directory structure, where the user doesn't have perms. Try saving to the Desktop, or user Docs folder. Alternatively, first drag the image to the desktop, then open in Preview.

Comment: They are saving to the desktop. docs folder has the same issue.

Drag to desktop from outlook is workable, but opening a TIFF from the desktop and saving as/export also has the same issue.

Comment: That is… rather odd. Drag something to the desktop, then Get info to see the perms.

Comment: did that. they are as expected- owned by the user. i did a permissions repair, disk first aid (fsck) etc. happens to every user on those two computers. and the 2nd computer i personally wiped and reloaded in the last month.

Comment: The Desktop and the Docs folder are often included in your iCloud sync.  As such, I think apps need to be given permission to write there.  Check your iCloud settings first, and then also try to save to another folder under the user's homedir, but not part of iCloud.  Also check System Prefs -> Security -> Privacy -> Files and Folders, and see if the Preview app has permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test on my outlook client(version 16.54(21101001)), the .tiff and .jpg file can be saved as .jpg successfully, which didn’t reproduce your issue.

In order to check if the issue is related to the Outlook client, please log in to web mail and other email client(such as Mail client) to do the same test and check if the file can be saved as .jpg file successfully. If the issue is only occur on Outlook client, please uninstall and reinstall to check if there're any differences.

If the issue occur on different client, this may related to the some settings in your computer. Through my research, I found a similar issue that mentioned the error prompted when the file saved in Xcode. Please refer to Michael's answer in this thread, which may be helpful to your issue: Xcode: "[The document could not be saved. You don’t have permission."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051228/xcode-the-document-could-not-be-saved-you-don-t-have-permission#:%7E:text=Fixed%20by%20changing%20account%20name%20by%20following%20this%20guide.%20This%20essentialy%20creates%20a%20new%20account%20but%20with%20your%20old%20Home%20directory%20and%20within%20the%20process%20of%20transferring%20it%20fixes%20some%20file%20permissions.).

Comment: The real issue is that nothing can be saved from "Preview" to the desktop unless it's a pdf/tiff or jpg2000. I can open any image file from anywhere into "Preview" and I can't save it to jpg.

The laptop is a fresh reload of the OS, which I had hoped would fix it.

Comment: Have you tried to do the same test on web mail? And you can also log into other mail client, such as Mail, to check if the same can be saved successfully.